# Get messages from thread

Tags: java, multithreading

In First class have method "listen" which listening client socket

```
public void listen() throws IOException {       

        while (true) {
            socket = this.serverSocket.accept();

            DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream( socket.getOutputStream() );
            this.outputStreams.put(socket, out);


            Thread miltiServer;

            miltiServer = new Thread() {
                @Override
                public void run() {                    
                    InputStream sin = null;

                    try {                   
                        sin = socket.getInputStream();
                        ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(sin);
                        message = (AgentData) in.readObject();

                    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {

                    } catch (IOException ex) {

                    } 
                }
            };

            miltiServer.start();
        }
```

In Second class i need to read and analyze messages which recieved from client socket. I don't know how to get messages in other class. I have idea to use Callable interface, but if i use it, return statement will exit from infinitive cycle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy way for your socket listener to communicate the messages to your `Second` class is through a [`BlockingQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html).  The listener would read from the socket input stream and call `queue.put(...)` to add any messages to the queue.

Then the Second class would be in a loop calling `queue.take();` which would return each message when it is added to the queue.  If you want unlimited messages to be queued then [`LinkedBlockingQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html) would work.  If you want to throttle the messages then a bounded queue such as [`ArrayBlockingQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ArrayBlockingQueue.html) might be more appropriate.

Both threads would need to share the same `BlockingQueue` so you will need to construct it and pass it to both threads or put a method on your `Second` class named something like `addMessage(...)` and the `BlockingQueue` would be inside of your `Second` class.  Then the listener would call `second.addMessage(...);`.